# Use different shell based on which device woke the PC?

Tags: windows, shell, startup, steam, winlogon

I'm trying to accomplish the following:

When my PC is woken from sleep with the Steam Controller, it lunches directly into Steam Big Picture Mode, without showing the Windows desktop first.

Ideally I'd like to be able to exit from Steam BPM back into Windows desktop, without having to start explorer.exe manually. So explorer.exe should be running in the background, I think.

Could anybody suggest how I could go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could [attach a script](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/otto/2007/11/09/reference-the-event-that-triggered-your-task/) to the [wake-up event](https://superuser.com/questions/84442/trigger-task-scheduler-in-windows-7-when-computer-wakes-up-from-sleep-hibernate), then have your script check [wake-up source](https://serverfault.com/questions/210166/event-log-wake-source-when-system-wakes-from-sleep) and if it's Steam controller, [launch Steam in Big Picture mode](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_browser_protocol).

This is general outline. The burden of implementation, falls on your shoulders.

Comment: Thanks! This worked reasonably well, except once the computer starts up, it does show the Windows desktop for a second or so before lunching into BPM. Is there any way to skip that...?

Comment: @user1073407 The delay between resuming from sleep and starting Steam is unavoidable. But you can hide desktop window/icons and or show some sort of splash-screen _before_ your system enters the sleep. Attach script to  `Kernel-Power` event with ID `42` to do this.

Comment: @user1073407 And if you don't mind brute-force solutions, you could also just kill Explorer before sleep and start it again after wake up if needed.